# How to exclude package-info.java files from dex?

Tags: android, dex, package-info

I have a multi-module Android application and when I build the release APK, I get this dex error:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/XX/package-info;
```

I do of course have a `package-info` file in all my modules and they all have the same name.
Why does dex even care about `package-info` files, and how can I configure it to ignore them?

Note: I do **NOT** want to enable multi-dex

Comment: What are the reasons for having the same package in multiple modules? Would it make more sense to create unique (sub)packages across modules?

Comment: in a layered architecture you have the same package in different modules and thus you can use package-visibility for access-control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to exclude the `package-info` files from the jar files.

Example code to use in `build.gradle` files

for **java-modules**:

```
jar {
    exclude('com/**/package-info.*')
}
```

for **android-modules**:

```
android {
    sourceSets.main.java.filter.exclude 'com/**/package-info.*'
}
```

Works with:

- Android Studio `3.0 Canary 5`
- Gradle `4.1-milestone-1`
- Android gradle plugin: `3.0.0-alpha5`

**Note**: you can of course only then exclude the `package-info` files if they don't contribute to your build!
e.g. when you use [immutables style-configuration](https://immutables.github.io/style.html#apply-style) in your `package-info` file then you cannot exclude the files from the build, because then the names of the generated files may change!

Answer (score 0):

Try with using packagingOptions inside android tag in build.gradle for app module.

```
packagingOptions {
exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
}
```

More: [Packaging](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html)

Comment: `exclude` seems not to work for `package-info` files - maybe because they are java-source files?